# root unable to use system clipboard in vim 8.2

Tags: vim, clipboard, root

I have Vim version 8.2 installed (gvim package on Arch Linux). I have both +clipboard and +xterm_clipboard features. In my ~/.vimrc I have `set clipboard=unnamedplus` and created a symbolic link to this file in /root so that I only need to edit one config. The problem is that yanking and pasting works only for my regular user account but not for root: if I run vim as root I can't even copy to system clipboard using "+y command: both *PRIMARY* and *CLIPBOARD* registers stay unchanged.

My terminal emulator is Konsole 20.04.0. Any thoughs as to what might be causing this weird behavior? It might be worth noting that I use su -l to get a root shell.

Comment: Dont use the symlink. Use sudoedit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access the X11 clipboard, it's required that the `DISPLAY` variable be set to the proper value and the magic cookie (that is, the authentication token) be accessible.

Usually, if you're using `sudo` or `su` to run as root, the environment variables are cleared for security reasons, so you're probably missing the `DISPLAY` environment variable.  You can either set the `DISPLAY` environment variable explicitly when changing shells (e.g., `export DISPLAY=:0.0`) or use some script to dump and reload certain environment variable to and from a file, or you can skip the `-l` flag for `su` or use the `-E` flag for `sudo`.

Note that these latter two options are poor for security, but in general it's not a good idea to let root access the same X11 session as an unprivileged user, so what you want to do is not great for security in the first place.  If you're the only user on the system it might be okay, depending on your level of comfort and threat model.

Comment: I've tried setting the DISPLAY environment variable both to :0.0 and to :0 (the value of the regular user) — neither have worked. But since you say it's not a good practice to do so anyway, I guess I'm just gonna leave it as it is. Thank you for the advice! )

Comment: It's not enough to set `DISPLAY`. You need to allow root to access the X session using `xhost` (very bad for security) or `xauth` (better).